# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ... method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Tags: c#, asp.net

MVC 5, C# - 
I am creating a view model based upon different sets of data in my database. I have the following code to create the View Model.

```
    public ActionResult Register_step6()
    {
        CoreGeneral cg = new CoreGeneral();

        var model = (from p in db.WorkPointRoles
                     select new RegisterEmployee_Step6Model()

                     {
                         Role = p.Role,
                         Selected = false,
                         RoleDescription = cg.GetRoleDescription(p.Id)
                     });

        return View(model);

    }
```

I receive the following error message :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   GetRoleDescription(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

I understand that the message has something to do with the Entities not recognising my GetRoleDescription code because it is placed in the select statement - (I've porbably worded my understanding incorrectly).. anyway, how do I solve the problem, where can I put the GetRoleDescription so that it runs on every record returned?

I hope this makes sense to someone! Apologies for the poorly worded question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What `GetRoleDescription` does?

Answer (score 2):

You should perform projection to `RegisterEmployee_Step6Model` in-memory instead of SQL Server side.

```
public ActionResult Register_step6()
{
    CoreGeneral cg = new CoreGeneral();

    var model = (from p in db.WorkPointRoles
                 select p).AsEnumerable()
               .Select(r => new RegisterEmployee_Step6Model()
                 {
                     Role = r.Role,
                     Selected = false,
                     RoleDescription = cg.GetRoleDescription(r.Id)
                 });

    return View(model);

}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked perfectly! this is an area that i'm not too hot on just yet!

Comment: You can ommit the first select query and use just `db.WorkFopintRoles.AsEnumerable().Select(...)`. The `select` query is left just in contrst for your LINQ query.